# Modifcação de CSS interno com PHP

Tags: php, css

Estou com o seguinte problema: eu tenho esse campo  que modifica a cor da div seguinte. Ele precisa estar dessa forma. Esta div receberá dados vindos do banco de dados, entre eles, a cor que a div terá. O problema é: quando eu carrego a cor do banco de dados, muda todas as divs para a última cor carregada, mesmo colocando o foreach para carregar a cor no campo certo.
Alguém tem uma ideia?

```
    <?php foreach ($field as $f): ?>
      <style>
                        .sidebar-vaccine ul li.li-<?php echo $count ?> a { background: #<?php echo $cor; ?>; }
                        .sidebar-vaccine ul li.li-<?php echo $count ?> a::before{ border-left-color: #<?php echo $cor; ?>; }
                    </style>
 <li class="w-100 m-top-15 li-<?php echo $count ?>">
                        <a  class="w-100  d-flex wrap align-items-c b-radius-10" 
                            href="<?php echo site_url ('Vacinacao/vacinas/1') ?>"
                            title="">
                            <span class="flex-<?php echo $count ?>">
                                <?php echo strtoupper  ($f->nome);   ?>
                            </span>
                            <figure>
                                <img src="<?php echo $f->icone ?>" title="<?php echo strtoupper  ($f->nome);   ?>" alt="">
                            </figure>
                        </a>
                    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Não é assim que o CSS funciona. Seria melhor você ler como funciona o seletor CSS e aprender a utilizar classes para deixar marcado alguns elementos e outros não com o PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Mano usa o while e não o foreach, o foreach e usado para array, vou mandar um exemplo abaixo.

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

$bd = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'banco');

$select = "SELECT * FROM...";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $select);

if ($query->num_rows > 0)
{

while ($listar = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

```
    <style>
        #div {
            background-color: <?= $listar['cor'] ?>;
        }
    </style>

    <div id="div">
        
        echo $listar['dado1'];
        echo $listar['dado2'];
        
    </div>

}
```

}

Comment: Leo, cara, testei aqui só agora. O problema é que estou usando o codeigniter 3 (por exigencia do projeto) e ele não está aceitando o while como laço. Tanto com for quanto foreach, convertendo o resultado para array com result_array(), ele dá o mesmo resultado, todos os campos com a cor do último resultado. :(

Comment: Cara nesse caso não sei o que fazer pq não conheço o codeigniter, vou ficar te devendo